# Training data for YOLO

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I am trying to train a YOLO model.
For this purpose I have divided my input image of 224*224 into 14*14 grids.

Now if suppose theres an object its centre is located at Bx,By considering 0,0 as top left of image and has Bw, Bh height and width respectively.

```
Required_prediction=[Pc,Bx,By,Bw,Bh]
```

*where Pc is probability of required object*

Thus output of model will be 14*14*5.

My question is what should the output Label be ?

All boxes [0,0,0,0,0] and the box containing the centre of req img as [pc,bx,by,bw,bh]
 **OR** 
All boxes [0,0,0,0,0] except whole area of required image labelled as [pc,bx. . . ]

*ALSO*

for bx,by,bw,bh the centre of the image is to be specified wrt to top left of the image or the grid the coordinate fall into?

Answer (score 0):

All boxes [0,0,0,0,0] and the box containing the center of req img as [pc,bx,by,bw,bh] is the right choice for the assumption that you divided the image into `14*14` grid.

but in real world problems they split the image using different sizes to solve this problem which means that you may split the image into `14*14`, `8*8` and `4*4` grids to address different sizes of the objects

Comment: suppose theres one or 2 required object of intrest in the pic, then i am labelling 2 boxes out of 14*14 with [pc,bx,by.....] which means my model will easily learn to predict theres nothing in the image as thats true for 90% of the grids except 2

Comment: That's true and i think that's what you want. the model need to learn if there is an object or not in the first place that's why you are using `pc`. take care that the loss function when `pc` is 1 is different than `pc` is 0